# PHP results in html table restricted to 3 in a row

Tags: php, html-table

I'm trying to get my search results to display on a page in table with 3 results per line (row). I have tried various ways and changed the script so many times but just end up going round in circles and coming back to my original script.

Eventually I want to restrict the output to 50 per page and 5 per row, but just getting it to display properly is the priority.

Any help would be fantastic.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
function searchmembers($search_term){
global $con;

        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `artist` WHERE `Band` LIKE '%$search_term%' OR `Genre` LIKE '%$search_term%' LIMIT 0, 30 ") or die (mysqli_error());
                $num_of_row   = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
            if ($num_of_row > 0 ){
                 while($row    = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                { 
                    $id = $row['Band'];
                    $Pic = $row['Pic'];
                 ?>
                 <?php

                    echo"<table>";?>
                    <td><img src="<?php echo $row['Pic']; ?>" height="100" width="100" align="middle" /></td>
                    <?php

                    echo "<td><a href ='profile.php?Band=$id' style='color:white; text-decoration:none;'>". $row['Band']."";




                    echo"</table>";
                }
            }
            else
            {

              echo "<font color='red' size='4' >No result found!</font>";
            }
}   
?>
```

Which gives this result:
[image: Screenshot of search results]

Comment: You want pagination?

Comment: Eventually, I just want it to display properly to start with.

Comment: You do a table in each cycle of while, but it's wrong. You must open a <table> tag before "while", and close "</table>" after it. In while you must place rows.

Comment: Thank you nearly there, just need to get them 3 in a row horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
function searchmembers($search_term){
global $con;
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `artist` WHERE `Band` LIKE '%$search_term%' OR `Genre` LIKE '%$search_term%' LIMIT 0, 30 ") or die (mysqli_error());
            $num_of_row   = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
        if ($num_of_row > 0 ){
             $i=0;
             echo"<table>";
             while($row    = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
            { 
                $id = $row['Band'];
                $Pic = $row['Pic'];
                $i++;
             ?>
             <?php if($i%3==1){ ?>
                <tr>
             <?php }?>
                <td><img src="<?php echo $row['Pic']; ?>" height="100" width="100" align="middle" /></td>
                <?php

                echo "<td><a href ='profile.php?Band=$id' style='color:white; text-decoration:none;'>". $row['Band']."";


              <?php if($i%3==1){ ?>
                </tr>
             <?php }?>


            }
            echo"</table>";
        }
        else
        {

          echo "<font color='red' size='4' >No result found!</font>";
        }
```

Comment: change if($i%3==1) to if($i%3==0)

Comment: Thank you nearly there, just need to get them 3 in a row horizontally.

Comment: With a little bit of tinkering I have this worked out, the lastif($i%3==1){ ?> controls results per row, the first controls the amount allowed within the table so I now have this set as <?php if($i%50==-0){ ?> and it seems to display correctly. Thank you so much for maintaining my sanity.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, just need to get 3 in a row horizontal ?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV3k4.png)